# Android vimeo video downloader

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, vimeo

I want to play vimeo video in VideoView, but here is problem.

Steps for downloading video in desktop is as follows(based on ossguy.com script):

- get page `vimeo.com/XXXClip_id` (tested with 67216430)
- parse web page and get signature and timestamp
- send request as in form of `player.vimeo.com/play_redirect?clip_id=XXXClip_id&sig=5e23c571c4032abd7507368237f43a2a&time=1378707147&quality=hd&&codecs=H264,VP8,VP6&type=moogaloop_local&embed_location=`  (sig and time is obtained above)
- above request will start downloading from web page and response header contains "Location" header, which contains url for video in form of http://pdl.vimeocdn.com/70693/759/167687374.mp4?aksessionid=5e23c571c4032abd7507368237f43a2a&token=1378715414_ca8e14d352c93df0d33bbbadc3c888ac

I want to repeat same steps in android, since URL obtained from last step can be played with VideoView. But the problem is when send same request from step 3, response doesn't contain "Location" header. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone needs answer, I posted my solution.
Below is my function httpRequest(), which I've used in each step in order to obtain page and response headers. I'm assuming that I had a problem with redirects when I used DefaultHTTPClient, since "Location" header will be given in step 3, where it actually should be redirected.

```
public URLConnection httpRequest(String path) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(path);
        conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);  //you still need to handle redirect manully.
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
        conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In android

First of all add `io.vov.vitamio.widget` package in your project .

1. Then define a videoview in your `xml` layout file ...
2. Then use this code in your java file. Make sure that you are importing packages available in vimeo package

   videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));

   videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

   videoView.requestFocus();

   videoView.start();

Comment: I need 'path' variable set to link similar to step 4, problem is getting that url in order to do playing via streaming, I am using vitamio, but if I set link similar to in step 1 and 3, it cannot play video.